# MFC show images at the runtime in a Picture Control

Tags: c++, mfc

Can someone help me to show images at the runtime in a Picture Control in MFC C++? It means opening the video camera in a picture control

I have no idea how to do that..

Comment: No please it is not duplicated.. I want pictures at runtime. it means opening the video camera in a picture control

Comment: Fix your question and specify that you want to display the video stream. Are you using DirectShow?

Comment: Actually, I have no idea how to show video in a picture control.. So Now I am learning what DirectShow is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **Sample Grabber** (DirectShow) filter to accomplish this.

Read MSDN article on how to use the **Sample Grabber** at:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407288(v=vs.85).aspx